# vb.net Send Smtp Mail From IIS FormatException

Tags: vb.net, iis, smtp

Well i got a page that sends emails and everything runs fine in the developer web server but when i publish to a IIS Server i get a FormatException when i try to send the mail....
ex.Message = "the specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address."

the email is in this sample someone@gmail.com

Im using the "SmtpClient" and the "MailMessage" classes to send mails..

And the server runs windows server 2003

Edit:
Im using same smtp settings on the Dev Webserver as im doing in IIS.

Comment: Might want to change that 'smt' tag to 'smtp' :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any one gets this problem the solution is don't use the empty constructor of MailMessage!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Check that you've enabled local email relaying for the SMTP service on your Windows Server 2003 box. By 'local' I mean that applications on your local machine can use the SMTP service to relay emails - but you almost certainly don't want to allow external connections to do the same.

Comment: Assuming of course that you are using a local SMTP service..
Open up the IIS MMC and go to the SMTP service.
Edit the properties to allow local connections (eg. 127.0.0.1)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have any invisible whitespace around your email address. For example, if you are getting the email from a database, or input control, try trimming it, like:

```
mail.To.Add( New MailAddress( txtEmailAddress.Text.Trim() ) )
```

Comment: Good idear but didnt help... any way it works in my web developer server but not on one of our IIS Servers
...